# How to keep refreshing a canvas using Tkinter?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

How do I keep updating a `tkinter` canvas, like in a `while ( True ):` loop?

I know that you can do `after( 1000 , refresh_function );`, but how do I make the loop repeat forever?

Practical example: a program that draws a line with fixed length under an angle, and the angle is constantly increasing (so the line is rotating / spinning).

I think I have taken a look at all relevant questions here, but this may still be a duplicate, and if it is, I am sorry.

Comment: I just gogled it, thanks, that's exactly what i needed :)

Comment: So I'll add an answer for it ;)

Answer (score 4):

A `while True:` loop in incompatible with using `.mainloop()`.  You make a function repeat by having it re-schedule itself before it exits.  There are several examples in other answers, such as making something glide across a canvas. Here is another that illustrates the idea.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.StringVar(root)
label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=text)
label.pack()

def add_a():
    text.set(text.get()+'a')
    root.after(500, add_a)  # <== re-schedule add_a

root.after(500, add_a)  # <== start the repeating process
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I noticed i was getting an error at the end of my execution when i was using while True: ... This is an admirable method. I like it a lot! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps class [threading.Timer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects) could help you

```
def f():
    # write our code for repainting canvas
    # call f() again in 60 seconds
    threading.Timer(60, f).start()
# start calling f now and then every 60 sec
f()
```

Comment: Lol, I'm such a dumbass. I tried doing this:

'def _my_mainloop( self ):
  #code  
  self.after( 60 , self._my_mainloop )'

And i just got a stack overflow.

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I proposed threading to avoid the "while true" loop which could cause freezing of gui .. you're welcome

Answer (score -2):

To update a TKinter window (with canvas etc.), you'll need `root.mainloop()`, which equals in:

```
while 1:
    root.update()
```

Comment: Oh okay. I did find info about update( ) on google, but your answer makes it even clearer. I thought mainloop( ) is what actually keeps the window alive, and the window wouldn't exist before mainloop is called. Silly. Thanks mate!

Comment: This is a bad practice. While technically it will work, it's not a particularly good solution. Your GUI won't respond to events quite as smoothly as other solutions.